# Dynamic property selector lambda function

Tags: c#, properties, expression

I'm trying to build the property selector expression with the type and property name given. i.e. t => t.PropertyName.

The following code compiles just fine but results in empty value. Can someone please point to an error in the code?

```
    public static Expression<Func<T,object>> CreatePropSelectorExpression(string propName) where T:class,new()
    {
    var temp = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    ParameterExpression t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T),"t");
    MemberExpression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(temp),propName);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T,object>>(member,t);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't bother. Already found the solution.
Needed to use the member expression instead of temporary variable

Answer (score 10):

You don't actually need to create an instance of your object `T`, you're just creating some expression trees.  It all boils down to this really:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>> CreatePropSelectorExpression<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName), typeof(object));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of Expression.Convert()? It looks like it's working with just: var body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);

Comment: The convert method ensures that the expression is of a certain type. It boils down to being a cast in the end. It will be required if the property type is a `ValueType` since it will turn into a boxing operation. Though when building expressions, it's best to generate expressions of the expected type whenever possible.

Comment: Good but could you provide a nested selector with ``IEnumerable<string> propertyNames`` as arguments

Answer (score 1):

A nested version

```
static Expression<Func<R, O>> 
CreatePropSelectorExpression<R,O>(IEnumerable<string> propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(R));
    Expression selector = propertyName
         .Aggregate((Expression)parameter, 
               (a, name) => Expression.PropertyOrField(a, name));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<R,O>>(selector, parameter);
}
```